# Return multiple values with function in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe

Iam trying to calculate multiple values with my own function from a dataframe. The function currently returns only one value in a dataframe. It seems my for loop is not working correctly. I've also tried to put the results in a new list...

My dataframe:

```
     A         B         C          D          E 

ES  -0.03    -0.08     -0.07      -0.03      -0.11
```

My function:

```
w <- function(x){
    for(i in 1:length(x)) 
        {
        return( (1/x[i]) / (sum(1/x)) )
        }
}
```

The formula is correct because of the result. Does anyone have a solutions for my problem? Thanks!

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're trying to calculate. In the denominator, do you want to sum up values down each column, or across each row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't use a `for` loop, but vectorize your function and apply it directly to your vector. Something like this :

```
R> v <- c(-0.03, -0.08, -0.07, -0.03, -0.11)
R> (1/v)/sum(1/v)
[1] 0.32506596 0.12189974 0.13931398 0.32506596 0.08865435
```

Answer (score 5):

Juba's answer solves this problem but if you want to return multiple distinct objects from a function you can actually do that, too:

```
f <- function(x) {
  m.x <- mean(x)
  sd.x <- sd(x)
  return(list(Mean = m.x, SD = sd.x))
}
```